# How can I make this navigation bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I can use the animated bottom navigation bar package, but this package receives a list of iconData, but I want to use the svg file.

I can use the animated bottom navigation bar package, but this package receives a list of iconData, but I want to use the svg file

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert you svg image to a icon, follow this link:-
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-custom-icons-to-your-flutter-application/